# How to update, select and assign in a SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a scenario, where I have to return records, assign particular column to a variable and then update it accordingly. But I cannot do this till now. Any type of help will be appreciated.

Given below is the query:

```
SELECT     bd.booking_details_id, booking_date, booking_time, bd.user_id, bd.driver_id, u.FCMToken AS PassengerFCMToken,
           d.FCMToken AS DriverFCMToken, @NotificationCounter = notification_counter
FROM       BookingDetails bd
INNER JOIN [User] u ON u.user_id = bd.user_id
INNER JOIN [User] d ON d.user_id = bd.driver_id
WHERE      bd.booking_status_id  = @BookingLater
AND        booking_date          = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND        (notification_counter  IS NULL OR notification_counter  < 1)
AND        Convert(Time, bd.booking_time) BETWEEN  @StartTime AND @EndTime



--Update notification counter
UPDATE     BookingDetails
SET        notification_counter  = ISNULL(@NotificationCounter,0) + 1 --Increment notification counter
WHERE      booking_status_id     = @BookingLater
AND        booking_date          = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND        (notification_counter  IS NULL OR notification_counter  < 1)
AND        Convert(Time, bd.booking_time) BETWEEN  @StartTime AND @EndTime
```

Comment: And you can't simply just UPDATE, without that extra SELECT step?

Comment: Both your queries look well written, at least at a glance.  What is the problem?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen when i run first query, it will display an error `A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.`.

Comment: You are trying to assign the session variable `@NotificationCounter` but you never use it in the `UPDATE`.  Can you explain this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear that tells you can't combine to assign a value for variable and select fields together. So, why don't you remove selected fields. Just assign a value to variable.

```
SELECT     @NotificationCounter = notification_counter
FROM       BookingDetails bd
INNER JOIN [User] u ON u.user_id = bd.user_id
INNER JOIN [User] d ON d.user_id = bd.driver_id
WHERE      bd.booking_status_id  = @BookingLater
AND        booking_date          = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND        (notification_counter  IS NULL OR notification_counter  < 1)
AND        Convert(Time, bd.booking_time) BETWEEN  @StartTime AND @EndTime
```

Comment: But i need other columns also

Comment: Well, It seems there is no option except applying two steps.